# Are line breaks in XML attribute values allowed?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I realise that it's not elegant or desired, but is it allowed (in well-formed XML) for an attribute value in an XML element to span multiple lines?

e.g.

```
<some-xml-element value="this value goes over....
multiple lines!" />
```

Yeah I realise there's better ways of writing that. I would personally write it like:

```
<some-xml-element>
<value>this value goes over...
multiple lines!</value>
</some-xml-element>
```

or:

```
<some-xml-element value="this value goes over....&#13;&#10;" />
```

But we have our own XML parser and I'd like to know whether the first example is allowed in well-formed XML.

Comment: The .NET XDocument parser accepts this as expected, but the attribute value is returned with a space, not a line feed as it would be in a text <value> as you second example. (Your question is not specific to .NET, but my sample data is. I don't know if this is part of the general standard or a .NET feature.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2004386/55452

Comment: made an example to a similar question that preserves newlines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29782321/611007

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260436/
-
related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004386/
-
related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289524/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue

Seems to say everything except `<`, `&`, and your delimiter (`'` or `"`) are OK. So newline should be, too.

Comment: One example when new lines are a good idea inside an attribute is for xsi:schemaLocation attribute in the Spring configuration, which can contain several URLs separated by spaces and thus be much longer than the screen width.

Comment: it is valid however the parser will normalize them to space, [as Jan Cetkovsky says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8188290/611007).

Comment: Well ... I use multiple lines for long if/when test statements in XSLT documents.

Answer (score 55):

It is allowed, however according to W3C recommendation your XML parser should normalize the all whitespace characters to space (0x20) - so the output of your examples will differ (you should have new line on the output for "&#13;&#10;", but only space in the first case).

http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#AVNormalize

Answer (score 4):

.NET only:
If you're not sure if target string is valid xml attribute (and provide this attribute's value via code), you can always use [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) function to escape invalid characters.

According to the description of this function, the only invalid characters are:

`<`, `>`, `&`, `'`, `"`

And this means (as my predecessors wrote), that new line should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the first example is a valid one.