# How to detect new line from the parsed XML with simpleload_xml_string?

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SimpleXML doesn't preserve line breaks in XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457333/php-simplexml-doesnt-preserve-line-breaks-in-xml-attributes)

I have following XML

```
$xmldatas = '<layer text="name

id"></layer>';
```

I have parse this XML with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmldatas);
```

But when I checked the $xml, the `\n` is been replaced with space. I want the new line remains as it is after the xml parsing.

But how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that xml will accept a new line character in the tag option text.
If you are generating the xml maybe you want to do something like this?

```
$xmldatas = '<layer><text>name
id</text></layer>';
```

Comment: I'm getting that xml data from the flex... And in that I'm getting the new line..