# how to give line breaks in xml file using php?

Tags: php, xml

I am display mysql data in xml file using php.

there I used  this one in here i want to give line breaks .if we give line breaks that will display line break tag in content ..we have to give html tags .but we dont show them in xml content ...

the output is coming like this..

At the same time I want to remove that empty p tags also ...that is.

```
<![CDATA[ <p> </p>]]>
```

this is the code i have written for xml ...

please solve this  problems
                       header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
                    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
            $this->view->data=$this->CallModel('posts')- >GalleryAndContent();
                         $xml = '
                                    
                                    ';
                    $xml.='Thehansindia
                http://www.thehansindia.com
                Newspaper with a difference'; 
                              foreach($this->view->data as $values)
            {
                $output=strip_tags($values['text_data'],"

");
                $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1',$output);
            $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) class=".*?"/i', '$1', $output);
            $output=preg_replace( '/style=(["\'])[^\1]*?\1/i', '', $output, -1 );
             $output=preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(/?)>/i",'',$output);
                     $output=str_replace(array("",""),array("

","

"),$output);
            $output=str_replace(array("",""),array("

","

"),,$output);

```
    //$xml.="<CONTENT>"."<![CDATA[".$output."]]>"."</CONTENT>
                           $xml.= '<item>';

             $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($output);
            $xml.="<CONTENT>";
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag){

       //$tag->nodeValue=str_replace("<![CDATA[ <p> </p> ]]>","",$tag->nodeValue);
                         if(!empty($tag->nodeValue)){                       
     //$tag->nodeValue=str_replace("<![CDATA[ <p>& & &</p> ]]>","",$tag->nodeValue);

        $xml.="<![CDATA["."<p>".stripslashes($tag->nodeValue)."</p>"."]]>";

                            }
                            }
                      $xml.="</CONTENT>";
                         $xml.= ' </item>';
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider supplying actual code instead of an image. It's much work work for your potential helper to recreate sample code if s/he can't copy-paste from your supplied example.

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of code but provide code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
//Next replace all new lines with the unicode:
$xml = str_replace("\n","&#10;", $xml);
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457333/php-simplexml-doesnt-preserve-line-breaks-in-xml-attributes)