# How to have line breaks in XML attributes?

Tags: xml, new-operator, lines

I have a attribute called: description and I want to have the following in it with new lines:

> This is the content description section.
>    Download instruction:
>    This is the contents on how to download contents.
>    Hotline support:
>    This is the hotline for contents.

How do I create a new line for it in xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are line breaks in XML attribute values valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449627/are-line-breaks-in-xml-attribute-values-valid)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically you want to insert CRLF:

CR code: `&#13;`
LF code: `&#10;`

```
<myelement description="line1&#13;&#10;line2&#13;&#10;line3"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need it in XML *attribute*, you'll have to use character entities:

```
<element attribute="First line&#10;Second line&#10;Third line..." />
```

Answer (score -5):

Try it like this:

```
<description><![CDATA[first line<br />second line<br />]]></description>
```

Basically you wrap the content within your tag inside "" for the closing tag, inbetween this tag you can use 
 to cause a line break. If you want to double space it, use two 
 like this:

Hope this helps.

Comment: Next time being more specific would be great. My method works perfectly fine withing the description tag.