# Liner break or put big text in preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-xml, line-breaks

I have `SwitchPreference` element in preference.xml .It contains a very large text that I want to break it so it can come in separate lines. If I leave as it is the text hid behind the sitch button. I already tried `<br/>` and `\n` but they are not working.

```
<SwitchPreference
 android:key="testKey"        
 android:title="Share activity \n on Facebook" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring your prefernce like this

```
<com.yourpackage.MySwitchPreference 
android:key="testKey"  
android:title="Share activity \n on Facebook" />
```

After extending the `SwitchPreference` to create
your custom `MySwitchPreference`  :

```
public class MySwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference{

public MySwitchPreference ( Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onBindView( View view){
    super.onBindView(view);
    adjustViews(view);
}

protected void adjustViews( View view){
    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup group=(ViewGroup)view;
        for ( int index = 0; index < group.getChildCount(); index++)
            adjustViews(grp.getChildAt(index));

    } else if (view instanceof TextView){
        // adjust your textViews here
        TextView t = (TextView)view;
        t.setSingleLine(false);
        t.setEllipsize(null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `&#13;` (CR) and/or `&#10;` (LF) in the attribute. On Linux/Android LF should be sufficient to force a line break.

References:

- [How to have line breaks in XML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823979/how-to-have-line-breaks-in-xml-attributes)