# String attribute values in multiple lines, HTML

Tags: html, string, split

Is it possible, in HTML to write something like:

```
<a href="bla bla bla bla\
        bla bla bla bla">....</a>
```

The idea is splitting a string attribute in different lines to improve readability.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393159/xml-split-attribute-value-on-multiple-line. laaposto's solution is probably your best bet, though I wouldn't be happy about it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes that's possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874964/3135511
The secret is to use **tab**'s instead of **space**
As well as to use linebreaks

```html
<a href="
 bla 
 bla bla 
 bla bla bla 
 bla bla 
 bla
 ">....</a>
```

^- try out the code and hover over the **....**
And look for the link - it should read just like 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Background:

- A space in a string will be escaped to %20 and so stay in,
  +but white spaces as **tab** & **line break** will be discarded/filtered out.

  If you want them in a string write `%09` for Tab  and `%0A%0D` for some CR/LF windows line break. -> *That are two bytes one
  **C**arrier **R**eturn char and some **L**ine **F**eed char.*

Comment: Note that this may not work in the near future. URLs with newlines are [deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5735596811091968).

Comment: This no longer works as described. HTML5 allows new lines and space characters inside the value of attributes.

Answer (score 13):

No, it is not possible. HTML has no “line continuation” character. If you put a line break in an attribute value, browser behavior varies, but modern browsers behave in the manner documented in HTML5: a line break is allowed, and it is taken literally and stored as a line break in the DOM. This means that `href` attribute value is broken and does not work.

The best you do to alleviate the problem of long `href` values is to put such a value on a line of its own, without quotation marks:

```
<a href=
http://www.example.com/some-long-path/and-so-on
>link</a>
```

In contrast, the following is allowed and causes as two-liner tooltip (in modern browsers). The point is that the general syntax allows line breaks, but they have consequences, and the specific syntax of an attribute may forbid line breaks.

```
<a href=foo title="Hello
world">bar</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without any break character. Just like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com
/questions/
22831988/
string-attribute-values-in-multiple-lines-html">
LINK
</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9MXSa/)

Comment: It won't work with spaces, so formatting-wise it's still pretty ugly.

Comment: @deadghost Of course and it will not work with spaces. Space is also a character. If you add another character you change the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @laaposto suggestion as long as there's no space between lines.

If you don't want to follow that rule, then you need to use javascript to remove the spaces:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0; i<= anchor.length; i++) {
    var href = anchor[i].href.replace(/%20/g,'');
    anchor[i].href = href;     
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MXSa/1/)**

or easier with jQuery:

```
var href = $('a').attr('href').replace(/ /g,'');
$('a').attr('href', href);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6zBU/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can write in any ways but make sure that there is no any space between lines.

Linke this one

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow
.com/quest
ions/228319
88/string-attribute-values-in-multiple-lines-html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use PHP? If so you could do:

```
<a href="<?= "very "
             ."long "
             ."string" ?>">
```

Comment: Why not try it out / test it  by formating it as HTML snipped.
But yep to my taste this Syntax doesn't look very nice, even if it is correct for php

Comment: Because Stack Snippets don't run PHP, @Nadu.