# Adding a linebreak in some attribute string(like src or href ) in HTML / XML source

Tags: html, xml, line-breaks, entity-attribute-value

I like to improve readability and managing some HTML source code like this

```
<iframe src= "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LeaOiITAAAAAF_A-e9qjM6TCgdt4-rqixnkkatL                                   &co=aHR0cDovL3BsYXkuc3BvdGlmeS5jb20                                 &hl=de&v=r20160802154045&theme=dark&size=normal&cb=ap65yyq41qhy" title="reCAPTCHA-Widget" ...
```

I mean line breaking attribut names is the first step:

```
<iframe src= "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LeaOiITAAAAAF_A-e9qjM6TCgdt4-rqixnkkatL                                   &co=aHR0cDovL3BsYXkuc3BvdGlmeS5jb20                                 &hl=de&v=r20160802154045&theme=dark&size=normal&cb=ap65yyq41qhy"
        title="reCAPTCHA-Widget"
```

However is there a way of breaking down that long URL that i'll look somehow like this:

```
   "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor" +
        "?k=6LeaOiITAAAAAF_A-e9qjM6TCgdt4-rqixnkkatL" +
        "&co=aHR0cDovL3BsYXkuc3BvdGlmeS5jb20" +
...
        "&size=normal" +
        "&cb=ap65yyq41qhy"
```

Answer (score 5):

That's it:

```html
<iframe 
 src = "
  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor
   ? k = 6LeaOiITAAAAAF_A-e9qjM6TCgdt4-rqixnkkatL
   & co = aHR0cDovL3BsYXkuc3BvdGlmeS5jb20
   & hl = de
   & v = r20160802154045
   & theme = dark
   & size = normal
   & cb = ap65yyq41qhy
  "
 ></iframe>
```

Well the *secret ingredient* here is to use solidly **tab**'s instead of **space** when you are inside some string!
The parser will filter them out and you get some working url.

Comment: What if I have a text that is too long such as the Base64 encoded text of an image? I am trying to use it in Visual Studio and tabbing would take a long time.

Comment: Hmm doing that manually is tedious. Be clever use tools or create one yourself! Here's some example how to do it with a regular expression:  https://regex101.com/r/bLu2QZ/1
In Python ya may do it like this: import re
result = re.sub(r"(.{80})", "\\t\\1\\n", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI...")
So create a small script that'll read/write into the clipboard ( in py 'import win32clipboard') link it to a shortcut to perform the trick with a click.