# Activemq: How do I make the transportConnector uri more readable?

Tags: xml, activemq-classic

The transportConnector uri in my activemq.xml config file is over 400 characters and I need to add even more to it. This is making it too hard to read and later edit.

```
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2&amp;transport.enabledCipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA&amp;needClientAuth=true&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" />
```

Is there some syntax I can use to break this up into separate lines to make it more readable? Or can I configure the transport in another format, like a bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we're speaking of splitting a long xml attribute to several lines, right?

You can format your attribute string by using tabs like this:

```
<transportConnector name="ssl" 
                    uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?      
                         transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2&amp;
                         transport.enabledCipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                                                       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                                                       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                                                       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                                                       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA&amp;
                         needClientAuth=true&amp;
                         maximumConnections=1000&amp;
                         wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" />
```

For more details refer these posts: 
[Adding a linebreak in some attribute string(like src or href ) in HTML / XML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874711/adding-a-linebreak-in-some-attribute-stringlike-src-or-href-in-html-xml-sou/38874964#38874964)

[String attribute values in multiple lines, HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831988/string-attribute-values-in-multiple-lines-html/38880984#38880984)