# Conserve line breaks when reading multi-line text attribute with LINQ To XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

When reading an XML file with LINQ To XML (System.Xml.Linq), I need to be able to conserve the line breaks in multi-line text attributes.  Here's an example XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRoot>
    <Properties Description="Line 1
Line 2" />
</TestRoot>
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
const string xmlPath = @"C:\Blah\Test.xml";
var rootElement = XElement.Load(xmlPath);
var propertiesElement = rootElement.Element("Properties")!;
var descriptionAttribute =
    propertiesElement.Attribute("Description")!;
string description = descriptionAttribute.Value;
Console.WriteLine(description);
```

Expected output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Actual output:

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

*Note: I see this question is a duplicate.  The first answer to the other question works for me.  I will leave my question here, as the different wording of its title will provide another route to the answer.*

Comment: See [3.3.3 Attribute-Value Normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize): *Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or checked for validity, the XML processor **MUST** normalize the attribute value... For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value.*  So that is what you are seeing.  To successfully round-trip a line break inside an attribute, it must be escaped as &#10;.  See: [How to save newlines in XML attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004386).

Comment: After writing my answer I found a perfect duplicate: [LINQ to XML ignores line breaks in attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11466944).