# Line continuation in XML

Tags: xml, firefox, rdf

I am working with the Firefox `localstore.rdf` file. Although it is an RDF file the syntax is essentially XML. I am dealing with long lines.

```
<NC:persist RDF:resource="#nav-bar"
  currentset="unified-back-forward-button,history-button,feed-button,abp-toolbarbutton,widget:jid0-HFFmJoceGjTSKDBEWPpzfX9By7I@jetpack-hds-link-detector,firebug-button,personal-bookmarks"/>
```

I would like to break these lines to fit 80 character if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if Firefox trims whitespace per each element in the *currentset*:

```
<NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#nav-bar"
    currentset="unified-back-forward-button,history-button,feed-button,
        abp-toolbarbutton,
        widget:jid0-HFFmJoceGjTSKDBEWPpzfX9By7I@jetpack-hds-link-detector,
        firebug-button,personal-bookmarks"/>
```

You would need to test if that works. According to [Firefox sources](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bmo/qa/4.2/annotate/221/config/firefox/localstore.rdf), they keep the currentset attribute on a single line, always.

From what I know, even technically possible with XML (see [*Are line breaks in XML attribute values valid?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449627/367456)), the pretty-printers I know do not distribute an attribute value across multiple lines (please see [*Attribute-Value Normalization*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize)), so I would run some tests if you really need that as this depends on which value the application expects.

Answer (score 1):

XML doesn't care about whitespace between elements, or between attributes within an element. Break it wherever that works.

---

One thing that will *not* work is to break the line in the middle of an attribute value. There is no way to do that.