# Read and Write special characters in XML with minidom

Tags: python, xml, special-characters, minidom

I'm trying to write and read back a set of strings in elements called objects which has two attributes `name` (simple string ) and `body` the body is a string with special characters "\n" and "\" I'm using the following code for writiing the xml file :

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()
root = doc.createElement('data')
doc.appendChild(root)
#create a scene
scene = doc.createElement('scene')
root.appendChild(scene)
#add object element
object = doc.createElement('object')
object.setAttribute('name', 'obj1')

txt= 'Text\nsome text\nanother one\\and so on\n'
object.setAttribute('body',txt )
scene.appendChild(object)

#write to a file
file_handle = open("filename.xml","wb")
file_handle.write(bytes(doc.toprettyxml(indent='\t'), 'UTF-8'))
file_handle.close()
```

and it produces this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
    <scene>
        <object body="Text
some text
another one\and so on
" name="obj1"/>
    </scene>
</data>
```

and for parsing :

```
filepath = 'file.xml'
dom = minidom.parse(filepath)
scenes =dom.getElementsByTagName('scene')
for scene in scenes:
    txt_objs =scene.getElementsByTagName('object')
    for obj in txt_objs:
        obj_name = obj.getAttribute('name')
        obj_body = obj.getAttribute('body')
        print(obj_name,"  ",obj_body)
```

the output of the parser is not the same as the stored the newline special char is lost, how do i maintain the same output as the input

```
#parser output
obj1    Text some text another one\and so on
```

What is the proper way of storing and retrieving a string with special characters ?

Comment: Take a look at [lxml](http://lxml.de). It's very easy to start and can save lot of effort in aspects.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi thanks for the suggestion , but i can't use external library ,this script is for blender_3d so i need to use what's included in python by default only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior demonstrated by minidom is align with [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#AVNormalize). See the following discussion: "[Are line breaks in XML attribute values valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449627/are-line-breaks-in-xml-attribute-values-valid)". I quoted the answer by @JanCetkovsky here for easy reference :

> It is valid, however according to W3C recommendation your XML parser should normalize the all whitespace characters to space (0x20) - so the output of your examples will differ (you should have new line on the output for "
> ", but only space in the first case). [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188290/2998271)]

If you have control over the XML document structure (seems you have as you constructed the XML yourself), put the text as XML element value instead of XML attribute value :

```
.....
#add object element
obj = doc.createElement('object')
obj.setAttribute('name', 'obj1')

txt = 'Text\nsome text\nanother one\\and so on\n'
txt_node = doc.createTextNode(txt)
obj.appendChild(txt_node)
scene.appendChild(obj)
.....
```