# getting xelement to treat xml attribute value as CDATA

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xelement

I am trying to include html content inside an attribute value (e.g. `<tag attribute="<b>hi</b>"></tag>`). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289524/is-it-possible-to-have-html-text-or-cdata-inside-an-xml-attribute), it seems that this should be done by default on string attribute types, however I get the invalid character error. Is there a way to make XAttribute treat it as CDATA?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify XML attribute values as CDATA. What you can do you can escape the xml you want to place as a value:

```
<tag attribute="<b>hi</b>"></tag>
```

will become

```
<tag attribute="&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;"></tag>
```

If you are building a document and you want to add this attribute all you need to do is to add html in XAttribute constructor:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("tag", new XAttribute("attribute", "<b>hi</b>")));
```

To get the value as an xml document you can use this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<tag attribute=\"&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;\"></tag>");
var attributeValue = doc.Root.Attribute("attribute").Value;

var newDoc = XDocument.Parse(attributeValue);
```

Comment: thanks @Damian, I know about escaping html tags. However, I was referring to the XML spec in the post where it seems that you need not escape any tags for an attribute since it's by default treated as CDATA. I was just wondering if there was a way to get XElement to recognize this.