# How to read the attribute value which is within CDATA from XML in Talend

Tags: xml-parsing, talend

I am trying to read attribute value which is within a CDATA from XML in Talend. I am getting the value along with CDATA and not the value alone.
My XML format is :

```
<root>
   <node attribute="![CDATA[value]]" />
</root>
```

In Xpath if i give attribute it is retrieving the value as ![CDATA[value]]. I want to get only "value". Is it possible to get the value inside the CDATA?

Comment: it seems that you can't have CDATA inside an attribute. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289524/is-it-possible-to-have-html-text-or-cdata-inside-an-xml-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tMap or tJavaFlex set output value as:

```
row1.value.replaceAll("!\\[CDATA\\[","").replaceAll("\\]\\]","")
```

row1.value - change for You real name